# Swift 3 Cannot convert value of type '(String?,Error?) -> Void!' to expected argument type '((String?,Error?) -> Void)!

Tags: swift, swift3

I am working with the `LayerKit API` and once I converted the project to `Swift 3`, I got this weird **error**.

The code written is.

```
func authenticateLayerWithUserID(userID: String, completion: @escaping ((_ success: Bool, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)) {
    if let layerClient = layerClient {
        if layerClient.authenticatedUserID != nil {
            print("Layer Authenticated as User \(layerClient.authenticatedUserID)")
            completion(true, nil)
            return
        }

        // Authenticate with Layer
        // See "Quick Start - Authenticate" for more details
        // https://developer.layer.com/docs/quick-start/ios#authenticate

        /*
         * 1. Request an authentication Nonce from Layer
         */
        layerClient.requestAuthenticationNonceWithCompletion() { (nonce: String?, error: Error?) -> Void! in
            if nonce.isEmpty {
                completion(success: false, error: error)
                return
            }
```

> the "layerClient.requestAuthenticationNonceWithCompletion" line is
>   throwing the error: "Cannot convert value of type '(String?,Error?) ->
>   Void!' to expected argument type '((String?,Error?) -> Void)!'"

If I add parenthesis to match the syntax of the error, that throws more errors. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to comment out the whole method, retype it and find out what code completion suggests?

Comment: Also, as always with type mismatch errors and closures (and in general), you should drop the explicit type annotations, i.e `layerClient.requestAuthenticationNonceWithCompletion() { nonce, error in ...`

Comment: I tried your suggestions and it seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you both.